# Why is 2nd level nested list items not displayed when hovered over a hyperlink?

Tags: html, css

I want **"News"** under **French** to be shown when `: hover` over French.

```css
ul#topmenu li a#HyperLink:hover ul {
  background-color: pink;
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<ul id="topmenu">
  <li class="langHorzMenu">
    <a href="#" id="HyperLink">French</a>
    <ul id="Submenu" style="display:none;">
      <li>
        <a href="#">News</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You cannot use JQuery or JS to show "News" when hovered over "French".
You need to use the ids. You can add new ids or class names.
How to fix this?

Comment: Try putting `!important` in `display: list-item !important;`. That should override the inline style.

Comment: @Adrian that didn't work

Comment: `a#HyperLink:hover ul` would select a `ul` element that is a descendant of the `a`, which it of course isn’t. Go read up on _sibling combinators_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following (smaller / optimized) solution:

```css
/** hide the submenu by default. */
ul#topmenu li ul {
  display: none;
}

/** show the submenu on hover of the menu item. */
ul#topmenu li:hover ul {
  background-color: pink;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="topmenu">
  <li class="langHorzMenu">
    <a href="#" id="HyperLink">French</a>
    <ul id="Submenu">
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

At the moment the CSS rule tries to select a `<ul>` element **inside** a `<a>` element. You can change your CSS rules a little bit to get some simpler rules.

You should also avoid inline CSS (e.g. `<ul id="Submenu" style="display:none;">`). Try to define all your CSS rules on the `<style>` element or on a external CSS file (recommended).

---

You can also extend your menu using the following:

```css
/** hide the submenu by default. */
ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

/** show the submenu on hover of the menu item. */
ul > li:hover > ul {
  background-color: pink;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="topmenu">
  <li class="langHorzMenu">
    <a href="#" id="HyperLink">French</a>
    <ul id="Submenu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">News</a>
        <ul id="Submenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">News</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work for you:

Just change the selection to `ul#topmenu li a#HyperLink:hover+ul` and `display: list-item !important;` and it will work fine for you.

```css
ul#topmenu li a#HyperLink:hover+ul {
  background-color: pink;
  display: list-item !important;
}
```

```html
<ul id="topmenu">
  <li class="langHorzMenu">
    <a href="#" id="HyperLink">French</a>
    <ul id="Submenu" style="display:none;">
      <li>
        <a href="#">News</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> if you are trying to get the `:hover` over the "News" you can also use  the following:

by adding

```
#Submenu:hover {
  background-color: pink;
  display: list-item !important;
}
```

after the  *"News"* is displayed if you try to `: hover` above it will not disappear.

```css
ul#topmenu li a#HyperLink:hover+ul {
  background-color: pink;
  display: list-item !important;
}

#Submenu:hover {
  background-color: pink;
  display: list-item !important;
}
```

```html
<ul id="topmenu">
  <li class="langHorzMenu">
    <a href="#" id="HyperLink">French</a>
    <ul id="Submenu" style="display:none;">
      <li>
        <a href="#">News</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `style="display: none"` from the child `ul` 
your HTML will be like this

```
<ul id="topmenu">
        <li class="langHorzMenu">
               <a href="#" id="HyperLink">French</a>
                            <ul id="Submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

add css

```
ul#topmenu li ul{
  background-color: pink;
  display: none;
}
ul#topmenu li:hover ul{
  background-color: pink;
  display: block;
}
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s6qn712o/2/)